# User defined date format in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I can't figure out how to tell VBA the correct date format, as it seems to assume in the wrong way around. So `CDate("24/02/2016 10:59")` is giving the correct date - dd/mm/yyy. However when it iterates through a date like `CDate("01/03/2016 00:59")` - it assumes number 03 is not a month but a day so VBA is assuming it's `mm/dd/yyyy`, so it's giving me a date `03/01/2016` which is wrong and messing my data. So how can I tell VBA it's actually dd/mm/yyyy format. VBA seems to automatically pick up nicely even if it's `"2016/01/14"`, but it's failing when it's not really obvious which part of numbers are months e.g. both `dd` and `mm`are less than 12.

I'm reading this date from a CSV file using `WS.Cells(irow, icol).Value`.

This is what I tried so far:

`datDate = CDate(Format(WS.Cells(iRow, iCell).Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))`

Comment: I am almost certain that this has to do with your regional date settings (I assume you are outside of US, correct?). US standard date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and VBA **uses this format** even if the regional settings in your Excel app are different. You'll most likely need to parse the date to ensure you get the correct month and day as @Gustav suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `CDate()` function encounters an ambiguous `"aa/bb/yyyy"` date string it will be interpreted according to the order that the Month and Day appear in the short date format defined by the Regional Settings in Windows.

For example:

When my machine is set to "English (United States)" with a short date format of `M/d/yyyy` then `Month(CDate("02/04/2016"))` returns `2`.

However, after changing my Regional Settings to "English (Canada)" with a short date format of `dd/MM/yyyy` then `Month(CDate("02/04/2016"))` returns `4`.

Note that this is different from the behaviour of the Jet/ACE database engine when interpreting ambiguous `#aa/bb/yyyy#` date *literals* in SQL statements. In that case it will always interpret them as `mm/dd/yyyy` regardless of the regional settings.

The best solution, as always, is to ensure that the string representation uses an UNambiguous date format, e.g., `2016/02/04` will *always* be interpreted as Feb 4.

Answer (score 2):

Use mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss like:

```
#03/01/2016 16:32:58#
```

or DateSerial and TimeSerial:

```
DateSerial(2016, 03, 01) + TimeSerial(16, 32, 58)
```

To parse the string, use Mid:

```
TrueDate = Dateserial(Mid(s, 7, 4), Mid(s, 4, 2), Mid(s, 1, 2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(s, 12, 2), Mid(s, 15, 2), 0)

s = "01/03/2016 00:59"
' Returns: 2016-03-01 00:59:00 

s = "24/02/2016 10:59"
' Returns: 2016-02-24 10:59:00
```

Comment: I'm trying to read data not trying to change the existing data, which comes in every month in this date format.

Comment: That was not what you told.

Comment: Gustav sorry to be vague, I edited my question. Sorry your code is still producing 03/01/2016 00:59:00. I'm getting very anxious!

Comment: No, you are just confused. The code returns the correct values - see edited answer with results.

Comment: if you do stuff within VBA Access it works just fine as you mentioned, my guess is when you read from Excel csv file, it might store your `s` as 03/01/2016. I stopped testing further - I will just change date format to yyyy/mm/dd for piece of mind. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you read from Excel, the don't import but link the range and specify the field as text. Then create a simple select query with the linked tables as source and apply the necessary converting to the field(s) and use this query for your further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the date before you convert. Something like this;

```
Dim strDate As String, strFormatDate As String
Dim dte As Date

strDate = "01/03/2016 00:59"

strFormatDate = Format(strDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:nn")

dte = CDate(strFormatDate)
```

This changes the date string to 01-Mar-2016 00:59 which should convert to a date data type without confusion.

Comment: Sorry this is not working either, it's still converting to "03/01/2016 00:59:00". If you test your code in a separate subroutine - it works fine, so is my previous code `CDate("01/03/2016 00:59")`. For the record, I'm reading this date from a CSV file using `WS.Cells(irow, icol).Value`. I'm very confused...

Comment: @Kudrat - try using `.Value2` instead of `.Value`

Comment: @Scott, sorry no success